# Why do these buttons (Accept all cookies - Customize settings - review your question) not work on my browser?

Tags: bug, cookies, browsers, cookie-policy

In some browsers, these buttons do not work.

> Your privacy
> By clicking “Accept all cookies”, you agree Stack Exchange can store cookies on your device and disclose information in accordance with our Cookie Policy. Accept all cookies Customize settings

[image: bug 1]

---

[image: bug 2]

This is probably a common problem of all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Can you define "not work"? What happens?

Comment: Which browser brand and which OS are you using? Any other firewall, anti-virus, ad blockers installed?

Comment: Probably relevant: [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161)

Comment: If you can open the developer console of your browser, what error message do you see there when click on those buttons?

Comment: A requirement of JavaScript from *cookielaw.org*  [has been observed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need#comment1200676_71208).