# In the 10k tools, all closed questions migrated to a site count toward the percentage of rejected migrations to the site, even ones not rejected

Tags: bug, migration, 10k-tools, migration-rejection

In the 10k tools page listing migration statistics to and from this site, it shows the number of questions migrated to and from this site in the last 90 days, with a breakdown of each origin or destination site. For questions migrated to the site, it lists the percentage of questions whose migrations were [rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/377214) here.

The [page here on this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) (requires 10k+ reputation here) lists three questions migrated to this site, two from Meta Stack Overflow and one from Arqade:

[image: Two questions migrated from Meta.SO, one from Arqade]

(The top says 17 questions since that includes 14 questions migrated from here to other sites, which are cropped out in the screenshot.)

The statistics states that the sole question to be migrated from Arqade to here in the last 90 days was rejected. However, the [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382235/why-do-these-buttons-accept-all-cookies-customize-settings-review-your-ques?noredirect=1) was not rejected. It seems like the percentage counter counts *all* questions that were closed on the site after getting migrated from the other site, including cases where closing will not mark the migration as rejected:

- Closing as duplicate
- Closing after the migration stub on the origin site has been deleted
- Closing at any time for any reason, if the migration was from a main site to its corresponding per-site meta

In this case, the first of these applies: the question was closed as a duplicate. The other two questions migrated from Meta Stack Overflow to here in the last 90 days are both open, which leads me to believe the percentage counter includes all questions later closed, not just those where the closure resulted in migration rejection.

Can the percentage counter please be fixed to only include actual rejections, not closures without rejections?